# How to add a password as blank in yaml?

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I have my enable password set as nothing. Basically I just hit enter to have access to my enable mode when prompted for a password. How can i configure this in yaml?

Answer (score 0):

In YAML empty scalars are usually interpreted as `null`, as indicated in the [specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786563). As this is not the same as an empty string, you should use

```
password: ''
```

or the equivalent:

```
password: ""
```